# Android app is closed after pressing home

Tags: android, button, destroy

When I press `home button` or `button to see what applications are running` - my app closes. I was trying to add `onPause()`, `onResume()` etc., but nothing. It happened in some time after refactoring.

Log-cat:

```
05-08 05:13:05.613: D/dalvikvm(655): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 806K, 75% free 5048K/19820K, paused 59ms, total 61ms
05-08 05:13:05.683: E/SoundPool(375): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.683: W/AudioService(375): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.683: E/SoundPool(375): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.683: W/AudioService(375): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.683: E/SoundPool(375): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.683: W/AudioService(375): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.683: E/SoundPool(375): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.683: W/AudioService(375): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.683: E/SoundPool(375): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.683: W/AudioService(375): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.683: E/SoundPool(375): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.683: W/AudioService(375): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.683: E/SoundPool(375): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.683: W/AudioService(375): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.683: E/SoundPool(375): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.693: W/AudioService(375): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.693: E/SoundPool(375): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.693: W/AudioService(375): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.693: E/SoundPool(375): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.703: W/AudioService(375): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
05-08 05:13:05.703: W/AudioService(375): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
05-08 05:13:05.713: I/ActivityManager(375): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} from pid 375
05-08 05:13:05.733: D/gralloc(49): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
05-08 05:13:05.733: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-08 05:13:05.743: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-08 05:13:05.743: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-08 05:13:05.743: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-08 05:13:05.743: E/SurfaceFlinger(49): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error -2009986491
05-08 05:13:05.743: E/SurfaceFlinger(49): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
05-08 05:13:05.743: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-08 05:13:05.743: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-08 05:13:05.743: W/WindowManager(375): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (266x425) to layer 21015
05-08 05:13:07.213: I/Choreographer(544): Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: post your code and error log pls!

Comment: Press or long-press? Both perform different actions.

Comment: Did you put a Log in your onPause() to check that your application is not executing the onPause() ?
add in your onPause () `Log.i("onPause","onPause starts !");`

Comment: post your log cat pls

Comment: After simple press. Not long.

Comment: Have you maybe enabled "do not keep activities" in phone developer options?

Comment: Actually it's happening only with this one application.. Another app are working and can be paused without problem..

Answer (score 0):

I found problem. Problem was that was not specified label of launcher activity in AndroiManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name="com.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```